# Partially deriving the Gelfand-Levitan equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Consider the partial differential equation:

$$\left(\Delta-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)u(x,t)=V(x)u(x,t),\qquad(\bigstar)$$

for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $V\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$.

One may determine that

$$u(x,t)=\delta(t+x-s)+K(x,s-t)\qquad(\bigstar\bigstar)$$

is a solution to $(\bigstar)$, where $K$ is the "dual fundamental solution" of $(\bigstar)$.

> What does "*dual* fundamental solution" even mean?

Note that I am familiar with the notion of fundamental solutions which are distributional quantities, $E$, satisfying $\mathscr{L}E=\delta,$ where $\mathscr{L}$ is a partial differential operator.

If we multiply $(\bigstar\bigstar)$ by $D(s)$, where $D:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the *scattered data*, is the reflection of the plane wave from the potential $V$, then we obtain

$$D(s)\delta(t+x-s)+D(s)K(x,s-t)\qquad(\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar)$$

Then integrating $(\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar)$ in $s$, we get

$$\int_\mathbb{R}D(s)\delta(t+x-s)\,\mathrm{d}s+\int_\mathbb{R}D(s)K(x,s-t)\,\mathrm{d}s$$

> Then, from this, how do we see that
>   $$D(t+x)+\int_\mathbb{R}D(s+t)K(x,s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$
>   is also a solution to $(\bigstar)$?

Comment: Simply use the $\delta$-function property $\int f(x)\delta(x-a){\rm d}x = f(a)$ on the first integral (using $\delta(x) = \delta(-x)$) and make a shift of the integration variable by making the substitution $s' = s-t$ in the last integral.